# What is the best way to flatten structure

Tags: jss, graphql

I have a structure where directly below the /home node I wish to have all the stores. Each store should have information like opening hours and address. This data was created as a component. This leads me to the following graphQuery:

```
query pages($path: String!) {
  item(path: $path) {
     name
    path
    field(name: "Hide In Menu") {
      value
    }
    #template is "Page Components"
    children(includeTemplateIDs: "A87A00B1E6DB45AB8B54636FEC3B5523") {
      #template is "Store"
      children(includeTemplateIDs: "D036D24FFB0757B59FC174C95E0E8A05") {
        heading: field(name: "heading") {
          value
        }
        address: field(name: "address") {
          value
        }
        open: field(name: "open") {
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the JS side of things I don't want to access the data in this way so I flatten the structure:

```
try {
    let b = {
        name: item.name,
        path: item.path,
        heading: item.children[0].children[0].heading.value,
        address: item.children[0].children[0].address.value,
        open: item.children[0].children[0].open.value,
    }
    store.set(StoreMap.BUTIKK.DATA, b);
} catch{

}
```

Is this the best way to do this? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of by doing this?

Comment: You can create your own GraphQL schema which will do the orchestration of content and will return contentn required format https://gary.wenneker.org/sitecore-jss-create-you-own-graphql-schema/  https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview

Comment: You might be right, but I thought the point of GraphQL was to not create separate endpoints for every query in an application?

Comment: If you have specific requirements then have to implement custom solution and it's on the similar line

Comment: I think you have already your best way, OOTB no options to flatten the structure in GraphQL